# $('elems').each() with fat arrow

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I started to use ES6 fat arrow function notation and I really like it. But I am a little bit confused about it context. As far as I know, keyword this inside fat arrow function refers to context where the function is currently running. I wanted to do some simple jQuery iteration like:

```
$('ul#mylist > li').each(() => {
   $(this).addClass('some-class-name');
});
```

But obviously this piece of code not working. How do I refer, inside fat arrow function, to current "LI" element in this specific code?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The each() method supplies two parameters to the callback-function. They are current index and the current item. Thus you could do the following:

```
$('ul#mylist > li').each((i, v) => {
   $(v).addClass('some-class-name');
});
```

Where the "v" variable is the current "li" element

Answer (score 5):

Because [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) in the arrow function context is the same as the calling context.

The `each` function provides a current element as the second argument to the callback so

```
$('ul#mylist > li').each((i, el) => {
  $(el).addClass('some-class-name');
});
```

Or in the given case there is no need to loop

```
$('ul#mylist > li').addClass('some-class-name');
```