# Get parent of element in jQuery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm completely stumped on this. I have three elements on the page with a class of `.topic-link`.

```
<div id="parent1">
  <a href="#" class="topic-link"></a>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
  <a href="#" class="topic-link"></a>
</div>
<div id="parent3">
  <a href="#" class="topic-link"></a>
</div>
```

I can run `$('.topic-link').eq(0).parent();` in the JS console and get the correct parent returned. But when I iterate over them I get an empty object each time.

```
$('.topic-link').each( () => {
  console.log($(this).parent());
});

// returns 3 empty objects
```

Comment: Maybe if people commenting that this can't be reproduced actually tried to reproduce it you wouldn't be posting

Comment: @KevinB The better answer is [$('elems').each() with fat arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548683/elems-each-with-fat-arrow)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Arrow functions don't have their own `this` so what you have **is not** equivalent to

```
$('.topic-link').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).parent());
});
```

In your case `this` is `window` (or `document` or whatever depending on scope it is called in)  which has no parent dom node

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, this is correct. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions _"An arrow function does not create its own `this` context, so `this` has the original meaning from the enclosing context."_

Comment: :facepalm: Thanks a bunch! I totally forgot that about arrow functions.

Comment: Apparently you can use arrow function syntax; you just need to pass in the arguments that `.each()` provides

Comment: @j08691 sure...but that doesn't make anything here incorect, nor does it say this is what you need to do

Comment: I didn't say you were incorrect. And I upvoted you. I think the best answer for this question would combine your answer and Tibrogargan's

Comment: @charlietfl My mistake. When I reproduced this I originally replaced the arrow function with a function as you did, but introduced my own issue with a typo.  Both work.

Comment: @Tibrogargan i was really focusing on the *"why"* only anyway

Comment: @j08691 there's not enough code to combine them.  I think charlietfl's answer is more concise - doesn't have the unused argument.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - The point is that arrow function syntax doesn't have a `this` of its own (charlietfl's point), however in this example if you pass it the arguments from `.each()` it will work (your point). I don't know what you mean that there's not enough code.

Comment: @j08691 you could change this to a "normal" (i.e. not arrow style) function that took arguments, and use either `this` or the second argument, but why?  You don't get any added value

Comment: Guys, it's cool. I got the answer I needed. Carry on.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but damn that's a cruel problem :p

Answer (score 4):

From @charlietfl's answer: You're getting this behavior because arrow functions don't bind their own `this`.

To continue using an arrow function the workaround would be to use the 2nd argument from [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), the value of the object/array.

Example (arguments are required since the `arguments` variable is also not bound):

```
$('.topic-link').each( (∅, value) => {
  console.log($(value).parent());
});
```