# Don't have access to top level variables in nested each loop. Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Using this code:

```
addDefaultComments() {
    $('.image').each((index, image) => {
      Comment.defaults.forEach((comment) => {
        debugger;
        $('#images').find(`ul[data-id=${imageId}] ul#comments-${imageId}`).append(`<li>${comment.commentContent}</li>\n`);
      })
    })
  }
```

At this `debugger` statement, shouldn't I have access to image and index? When I call them, it says they aren't defined. Isn't that weird?

Proof that something odd is going on:

[image]

[image]

Comment: (Side note on terminology: You don't "call" variables, you "use" them.)

Comment: Can you try using a regular function rather than a fat arrow function for your .each function. Not sure how jQuery implements .each, but I'm pretty sure they use an `arguments` object.

Comment: attached screenshots

Comment: wow changing it to a regular function worked @darthaditya. Wtf happened?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. The only scope difference in fat arrow functions should be for `this`.

Comment: Okay that's great. It's probably because jQuery uses an `arguments` object to iterate over the child nodes. Fat arrow functions don't play nice with the `arguments` object.

Comment: I suspect this is a debugger artifact due to the fact that the nested function doesn't use those variables, so they're not included in the closure.

Comment: Does this problem happen if you put `console.log(index)` in the nested function?

Comment: @darthaditya: No. It's true that arrow functions don't have their own `arguments` binding, but that has nothing to do with jQuery's use of `arguments` in *its* functions.

Comment: See [this MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments) for more information.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Maybe you're right, we are missing something here.

Comment: did I not put in enough code?

Comment: @Barmar same deal, just tried it.

Comment: @darthaditya If it's using `arguments`, that's used outside the callback function, how can it cause a problem inside the callback? The only issue I can think of with `.each()` and arrow functions is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548683/elems-each-with-fat-arrow with trying to use `this` in the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At this debugger statement, shouldn't I have access to `image` and `index`?

Yes, you should; and you do — unless they get optimized away because you're not using them. That's what's happening here. Chrome is aggressively optimizing the function because you don't actually **use** `index` or `image` anywhere. If you use them, they're there:

[image: Proof that it works fine with arrow functions in an up-to-date version of Chrome]

(Here's that fiddle if you want to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbe2pue0/)

They're only not there if you *don't* use them:

[image: Proof they aren't there if you don't use them]

(And here's that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbe2pue0/1/)

(I think it's very interesting that Chrome does this optimization in an arrow function but not in a `function` function...)

Comment: Okay, but then why does it work when using a regular function?

Comment: `(I think it's very interesting that Chrome does this optimization in an arrow function but not in a function function...)` ...Ah maybe a quirk in Chrome then. You learn something new everyday.

Comment: @darthaditya: Different optimization. Really, with the `debugger;` statement there, you could argue that it should optimize the arrow function like that (for this very reason). But it does (for now, anyway). But this is just debugger stuff; those parameters *are* in scope and if you use them in actual code, they'll be there (won't get optimized away).

Comment: yo this be cray cray